# Mails from PHP on XAMPP not being sent

Tags: php, email, xampp

How to send an mail from the website ..?
I am using html and php for my static website but it is not senting an mail through xamp server.... my php code is

```
 <?php
     $to = "my@domain.com";
     $subject = "Test mail";
     $message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
     $from = "from@domain.com";
     $headers = "From:" . $from;
     mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
     echo "Mail Sent.";
 ?>
```

but it is not sending an email..

can anyone help me..?

Comment: are you working on live or on local machine ?

Comment: `senting an mail through xamp server` Yes he does

Comment: Do you have a working smtp server and have you set the `smtp_server` setting in your `php.ini`?

Comment: http://expertester.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/how-to-send-email-from-xampp-php/ - configure you XAMPP to send emails

Comment: What SMTP server are you using?

Comment: @user1640432 Iam working in local machine

Comment: @Krister Andersson iam not set the php.ini  how to set that...

Comment: @Shailesh: You need to have test your code on live server ..its seems to fine but some time we can not sent out email form our local server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more likely that you are trying to send mail using your local machine. You could try the following:

1. Open the `php.ini`. You should know where it is located because it depends upon the particular server you're running.
2. Search for the attribute called `SMTP` in the `php.ini` file. Generally you can find the line `SMTP=localhost`. change the localhost to the smtp server name of your ISP. And, there is another attribute called `smtp_port` which should be set to `25`. E.g. in your php.ini file:

   ```
   SMTP = smtp.mylink.com.np
   smtp_port = 25
   ```
3. Restart the apache server so that PHP modules and attributes will be reloaded.
4. Now try to send the mail using the `mail()` function

   ```
   mail("you@yourdomain.com","test subject","test body");
   ```